# Problem with exporting/importing a value from an ES6 module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export

I'm trying to export a `const` from a JavaScript file and import that in another JavaScript file, but it's not working. I already tried any other exporting method but it's always throwing the 404 (not found) error.

Any suggestion?

```
export const tour = new Shepherd.Tour({

useModalOverlay: true,
exitOnEsc: true,
defaultStepOptions: {
  classes: 'shadow-lg rounded text-center font-weight-bold',
  modalOverlayOpeningRadius: 7,
  modalOverlayOpeningPadding: 5,
  scrollTo: true,
  useModalOverlay: true
 }
});
```

This is how I'm trying to import the variable

```
import { tour } from "./tour.js";
```

Comment: Where are you using that import? Check also your project structure. What is 404-ing? Check what file it's trying to reach and whether yours is in the correct place.

Comment: @VLAZ i'm using it in another Javascript file in the same Javascript folder. The erros says that the URL of the file cannot be found, but i have other identical imports and they work normally

Comment: I neither know what the base URL is, nor how you're using this, nor your project structure. If you have other imports that work and this one doesn't, I can only conclude that *this one* is different to the others. I don't know how. There is not enough information in the question to figure it out.

Comment: @VLAZ the url is a classic http://localhost:3000/